# Why does accessing my session variable return a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im setting a session variable but when I try to access it, it returns an object null reference exception, any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

For reference, here's the code where I set the user id

```
     public static bool SetUserID(int userId)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUserId"] = userId;             
        return true;
        //when the user logs in, this method is called and the user id is passed into it
    }
```

and heres the method where I try to access the session variable

```
    public int GetUserID()
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUserId"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Any help or advice ?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the two lines of code to see which one runs first? Rather than catching the exception, do a null check first and use `int.TryParse` to prevent it from occurring

Comment: Yes I did do the breakpoint but the code that sets the variable runs first, after then only does the code that try to access it run

Comment: What's your actual question? If it's why does your code throw a `NullReferenceException`, it's because you're trying to access a method on an object that doesn't exist. If the question you actually want answered is why is that session variable `null` then that's a different question. You haven't even actually confirmed that `HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUserId"]` is indeed `null`. You need to think about what question you actually want answered and provide all the information relevant to that.

Comment: If those two snippets run in the order they are shown in the same session then it would seem that you are either setting the variable to `null` elsewhere or your system is broken. We can't really say more based on the information available.

Comment: @jmcilhinney okay thanks, I’ll recheck the system and I’ll edit the post if I find a solution